# Regex that will match only if it starts with a pattern

Tags: regex

```
/[\w-:/]+/g
```

This regex matches all alphanumeric & underscore words (which may also contain characters like `-`, `:` and `/`).

How to change this regex so that it matches only if the words begin with `**:`, where `*` is any alphanumeric character? Example: match `xs:qwerty:asd-zxc`, but not `qwerty:asd-zxc`.

Comment: Perhaps add `\b\w\w:` before the first square bracket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `\b` [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) makes sure that the match won't start in the middle of a word:

```
/\b\w{2}:[\w\/:-]+/g
```

should give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

/[\w]{2}:[\w-:]+/g you can use https://regex101.com/ to test.